# Exporting Annotation data from DGN to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, annotation, dgn

When transferring my .dgn file to .shp in ArcMap, I can't export the annotations to .shp. I do not know why the outil "export data" is disabled.

However, when importing the file .dgn in ArcMap, I can see the annotations but the problem is it can't be exported to .shp

How would I fix this?

[image]

Comment: CAD-GIS interaction is not always as easy and straight-forward as one would imagine. You can't generally export data straight out of a dwg/dgn in Arcmap, and text is whole new set of headaches. I'm not that used to Microstation, but in Autocad Civil3d/Map you should use the `Mapexport` command. If you have access to FME there's an increased chance that you'll get relevant data from your dgn to a shapefile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Convert to geodatabase annotation using right click
2. Use Add geometry attributes tool to add EXTENT or CENTROID. This will populate table with one or two pairs of coordinate.
3. Export annotation table to standalone table
4. Use pair of coordinates of your choice from this table as input to Add XY Data, and convert resulting event layer to point feature class. This is where you can finally use Right Click. Note you can define any of 4 corners of annotation extent to be your anchor point

If you follow solution  by @geojwh you'll see the same thing, you see now, i.e. greyed out Data-Export Data item