# Putting layers to new place (another coordinate system) using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, annotation

I have a lot of feature layers  with annotation in geodatabase. I need put all layers to a new place (another coordinate system).

Firstly I export all layers to shapefile and then put it to new place.

But I can't move annotation feature class layers to new place (very long time process). I use editor and move it with control point. It happens fast but saving time is too long.

Does anyone know how to do it easier?

Answer (score 1):

Feature classes (including annotation) are projected from one coordinate system to another using the [Project](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) tool which:

> Projects spatial data from one coordinate system to another.

Comment: Input coordinate system is Unknown. i can`t project it.

Comment: @Jannik even though it does not have a coordinate system defined do you know what coordinate system your coordinate values are from?  If you do then just Define Projection it first.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this solution [Problem in exporting Annotation data to shp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186305/problem-in-exporting-annotation-data-to-shp/186380#186380) and then use **spatial adjustment** to bind a point feature class.