# How to append text string information from CAD annotation to polygon feature class attribute by location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, annotation

I have a CAD file with polygons. They are signed with an annotation.

Is it possible to assign text values from the annotations to polygon feature class attribute.

As I understand only the location connection between the text and the polygon.

[image: Annotation in imported CAD file]

Comment: Have you tried spatial join?

Comment: Try this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186305/problem-in-exporting-annotation-data-to-shp/186380#186380 and see if they seat inside correct feature. If not use attribute transfer.

Comment: @BERA Yes i tried it.The location of the text is not always good. First result of spatial join is only 60% of data. I think i need to change CAD annotation (size or position) to get a more correct result.

Comment: @FelixIP I try your link. In addition to all the annotations contain errors. Two values in one text. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND9PW.png

Comment: This is how cad works, shall I say doesn't work? It is not database system.

Comment: @ FelixIP What i need to do? Correct it manually?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, unless you see a patten.

Comment: @ FelixIP At first there was a vector in pdf. I imported it into the CAD. This could not change the position of the text?